# ¿Se puede VACIAR una tabla (truncate) cada X Minutos?

Tags: php, javascript, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Tengo una pequeña duda, en la que no he encontrado mucha información.

¿Podría hacerse algo, para cada "5 minutos" (por ejemplo) vaciar todo el contenido de una tabla?

La verdad es que he estado investigando, y no he encontrado nada de información útil.

Muchas gracias a todos de antemano.

Comment: quieres vaciar una tabla en php? javascript(html)? sql?.  Como dices *truncate* se entiende que es una tabla en MySQL pero lo que no se entiende es el uso de los tags php y javascript, quieres que el truncate de la tabla se haga desde una página web?

Comment: Sospecho que te sería más útil actualizar tus datos en lugar de rellenar la tabla de nuevos registros.

Comment: Si realmente necesitas eso, puedes tener un problema en el diseño de la base de datos, en caso contrario podrías realizar un cronjob en la base de datos que ejecute `TRUNCATE TABLE TABLITA_A_TRUNCAR`

Comment: no creo necesario el uso de cronjob pudiendo hacerlo en la misma base de datos

Comment: Es una tabla de uso "temporal" se usa en "determinados momentos" para facilitar mucho código de programación, al acabar se eliminan, puedo hacer esto, porque solo un usuario entrará aquí. Si dejaran la tarea a medias, los datos seguirían guardados ahí, por eso a los 5 minutos eliminarla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción para hacer esto desde la misma base de datos es crear un evento programado (schedule event) el cual puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera

Para saber si el scheduler esta activado usas esta query:

```
SELECT @@event_scheduler;
```

si no estuviese activado lo activamos con la siguiente query:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Y por último generamos el evento programado:

```
CREATE 
EVENT `truncateTable`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE STARTS '2016-03-23 00:00:00'
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
ENABLE
DO
TRUNCATE TABLE tuTabla;
```

Comment: Esto podría programarlo en la misma base de datos, desde PHP My Admin ???

Comment: si, solo necesitas tener privilegios super (administrador) para la query que activa el scheduler

Comment: a bueno y la última versión de MySQL (5.1)

Comment: Lo tengo todo, con lo que voy a comenzar a hacer pruebas, muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Javier

La opcion para vaciar una tabla cada 5 min, es que crees una tarea que se ejecute cada 5 min a nivel de sistema operativo, por ejemplo si estas en Linux creas un crontab que se ejecute cada 5 min donde le des el comando

ejecutas en una terminal como usuario root crontab -e 
y te abrirá el editor de cron donde podrias algo asi ejemplo :

*/5 * * * * psql nombredb  -c "TRUNCATE TABLE nombre_tabla;" -p 5432 -U postgres

en caso de usar Postgresql

en caso de mysql seria asi:

*/5 * * * * mysql nombredb  -e "TRUNCATE TABLE nombre_tabla;" -P3306 -u root -p tu_password

con esto borrarías la tabla cada 5 min

aunque si no tienes que resetear los id autoincrementales o seriales en vez de truncate usaría la sentencia delete